# .NET Compact Framework Printing libraries

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Can anyone point to libraries that can be used for Printing from Compact .Net Framework 1.0?

Criteria:

1. I need to be able to print Text and Bar codes.
2. The library should preferably be upgradable to .Net 2.0 or above with minimal disruption.
3. Can be either Open Source [that can be distributed as part of Commercial application] or that can be purchased.

*Edit*

More information:

1. We are an ISV and this application is sold to our customers.
2. This application is usually installed on Symbol, Opticon devices. But occasionally this is installed on a generic Windows Mobile PDA or Phone devices.
3. I want the library to work with Printers from multiple vendors. [I now have printers from O'Neil and Citizen-Systems for testing].
4. We want the printers to be connected using bluetooth. I guess the library should in general work with any serial port connections.
5. [PrinterCE.NetCF](http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE_NetCF.htm) from [FieldSoftware](http://www.fieldsoftware.com) appears to fit the bill. Thanks [ctacke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96218/net-compact-framework-printing-libraries#96899). I am looking for something similar.

Thanks,

Kishore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've not given us much detail, like the device you're using or the printer type you want to print to (local, lan, serial, network, etc), however I'll see if I can at least point you in the right direction.

The de-facto standard for CF printing is [PrinterCE from Field Software](http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE_NetCF.htm).  [PrintBoy from Bachmann Software](http://www.bachmannsoftware.com/pbce.htm) also works well.  I'm not certain if eitehr has the ability to print barcodes though.

Now if you're printing barcodes, that suggests that you're using a device like a Symbol (now Motorola) or Intermec handheld.  If that is the case then those manufacturers have their own SDKs that allow printing.

If you are printing to something like a Zebra barcode printer, they typically have some serial PCL commands for printing barcodes as well, so you don't actually need to "print" the barcode. Instead you send the PCL command to tell the printer that the data should be output a barcode instead of text.  The printer manufacturer can provide a PCL reference, as the PCL for these types of things isn't standardized.